# Simple clone of gradle test task not recognized as test in IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I want to have a very simple clone of a gradle task like this:

```
project.tasks.register("runTests") {
    it.group = "otherGroup"
    it.dependsOn("jvmTest")
}
```

The problem is, that the source task (jvmTest) is a test task. And when I do the simple dependsOn like in my example, intellij does not recognize it as a test task (e.g. it only displays the output in the build terminal but does not show the fancy green, yellow and red test symbols)

I tried to add it as follows

```
project.tasks.register("runTests", Test::class.java){ 
    it.group = "otherGroup"
    it.dependsOn("jvmTest")           
}
```

but this will result in a NullPointerException when running it

Answer (score 0):

`dependsOn` only creates an execution dependency on the task graph in Gradle, it will not create a different test task nor will it clone the one depended upon.

Have a look at [the sample on how to create additional tests](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/samples/sample_jvm_components_with_additional_test_types.html#header).